# how to add coded Web performance test to a load test in visual studio 2012

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, testing, visual-studio-2012

I wrote a `webtest` that calls a web-service with query-string.

I want to create a load-test that will execute this webtest ith different query-string on every request (from pre-definied values pool).

I didn't manage to do it with the regualt `webtest` file (anyone knows how?)

So I converted this `webtest` to `coded WPT`.

I edited the code and it looks like this:

public class KnownCtidsTest : WebTest
    {

```
    public List<string> KnownCtids { get; set; }

    public KnownCtidsTest()
    {
        this.PreAuthenticate = true;

        KnownCtids = new List<string>()
        {
            "ctelad1", "ctelad2", "ctelad3"
        };
    }

    public override IEnumerator<WebTestRequest> GetRequestEnumerator()
    {
        WebTestRequest request1 = new WebTestRequest("http://clientservice.mam.qasite-services.com/settings");

        request1.Method = "POST";

        var random = new Random();

        int i = random.Next(0,KnownCtids.Count);

        var ctid = KnownCtids[i];

        request1.QueryStringParameters.Add("ctid", ctid, false, false);
        StringHttpBody request1Body = new StringHttpBody();
        request1Body.ContentType = "";
        request1Body.InsertByteOrderMark = false;
        request1Body.BodyString = "";
        request1.Body = request1Body;
        yield return request1;
        request1 = null;
    }
}
```

Now, I try to add this coded test to the load-test (under `test mixture`)
but it doesn't show the `coded test` only the `web test`.

How can I still run my custom coded test in loadtest?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ran into this same problem, and when I moved on to other issues thinking I would come back to it later. The customizing extraction rules made it click to me what I had been doing wrong. Before you try to add a coded web test to a load test or another web performance test compile the project. This will generate the dll's that the UI is keying off of when it generates the list.